# MeteorJS app architecture guideline required

Tags: meteor

I am building a marketplace Meteor app but I am confused about the app architecture. I want to build front end user interface for marketplace, Customer dashboard, Vendor dashboard, admin user interface and meteor mobile apps for customers and vendors. I know Meteor bundle everything in client folder and send it to the client. My question is do I need to use same hosted Mongodb database and create separate Meteor apps for

- App 1  Marketplace user interface and Customer dashboard.
- APP 2  Vendor dashboard.
- APP 3  Admin user interface
- App 4  Meteor Mobile App for Customers
- APP 5  Meteor Mobile App for Vendors

OR

Create a single Meteor App for everyone. but in that case app size will increase.

OR

Create separate Meteor apps and connect all other apps to APP 1 (Marketplace App) through DDP to share publications and methods.

Please help me decide best architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

I've done so using a single MongoDb instance. I currently have four apps connected to it. It works really well.

Make sure you use the oplog for instant updates across all the apps.

Some of the security benefits of this approach were unexpectedly nice. For example, allow and deny rules being created with only one type of user in mind for each app. If someone has access to admin.yoursite.com for example, the permissions allow all sort of things for admins, but for the client facing app, the permissions can be locked down to only allow editing of the few things that are required.

You can get pretty far with this approach, I recommend it.

Option 2:

I wouldn't recommend making a large app that does everything.

Option 3:

Not to say there is no benefit to that sort of approach, but "APP1" in this case should probably be some sort of event log, which each app can subscribe to the events of and write events to, and update their own databases. This is the most complex (and expensive) solution, and I wouldn't recommend it until you are trying to scale really large. If you are interested in this type of approach I recommend looking into Event Sourcing/CQRS.